# Run + Debug a specific file when working with multiple open/active files

Tags: vscode-debugger

I'm new to VS Code so maybe this is obvious, but how can I run and debug a specific active file? I have multiple open files in my workspace and when I go to run the one I'm editing, VS Code continues to open a previously opened file instead of the one I'm working on.

I've tried closing the file that it continues to default to running but it's not recognizing the most recent edited file in my workspace that I want to run. How can I identify or isolate it to be the one that opens when I click run?

Comment: what programming language? what programming language debug support extension? any launch config? how _exactly_ are you running debug?

Comment: With a html file - I have the file open in VS code Editor that I'm editing and then go to top menu Run>Run without Debugging and it opens a chrome window but with an error code or says file isn't able to be accessed. When I try to click Run from the Activity Bar, it doesn't allow me to select the active file I'm working in. I don't know how to add a config or edit anything there so definitely open to suggestions!